# HorizontalScrollView inside TableRow

Tags: android, scrollbar, tablelayout, tablerow, horizontalscrollview

I have a TableRow inside a TableLayout. If I put a vertical ScrollView in the TableRow, it works as expected. However, if I put a HorizontalScrollView in the TableRow the scroll won't work at all.

Does anyone know why this happens? Could I use any workaround to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

--EDIT--

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow>
        <HorizontalScrollView android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TableRow>
                    <Button android:layout_width="350px" android:layout_height="350px" android:text="TEST" />
                    <Button android:layout_width="350px" android:layout_height="350px" android:text="TEST" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <Button android:layout_width="350px" android:layout_height="350px" android:text="TEST" />
                    <Button android:layout_width="350px" android:layout_height="350px" android:text="TEST" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

If I change HorizontalScrollView to a vertical ScrollView, it works (obviously vertically).

Comment: Post your layout xml and related Java.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Edit:

This should set the ScrollView to the size (content size) of the content insteat of the size of the place available in the parrent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to add some more explanation to your answer (why this fixes the issue, etc.) or at least keep that in mind for your future answers...